# Adding multiple slashes after the site URL breaks the current entry, but still loads the template

Tags: url, redirect, seo

I've come across an issue where typing the URL e.g www.sitename.com///about will still load the about template, but not fill the page with the content. Is this an issue for google finding the appropriate pages in google searches? And how can I get these pages to no longer exist or result in a redirect to the correct URL www.sitename.com/about?

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting the About template or the layout template it extends?

In a test with a local site I have running, I was able to trigger a 404 for any bad requests by putting

```
{%  redirect 404 %}
```

inside the `main` block in the `_layout` template.

This works in my case because that block is overridden on every request. If it's not, something has gone wrong and I need to exit out since the layout template should never render on its own.

Comment: I added {% if not entry | length %} as a conditional on the redirect and placed that in the _layout template. That worked a treat!